# Must every non-negative measurable function $f$ satisfying $\int f < \infty$ be bounded almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the statement in the question, but I'm wondering if what follows constitutes a valid counter-example. Let $S_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2^3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^3}$, and consider the function which takes the constant value $n$ on each interval $[S_{n-1}, S_{n})$. The integral $\int f\ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(S_n - S_{n-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$, and it seems $f$ is not bounded a.e.

Comment: For a simpler example, you can take $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ if $0 < x < 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Given any candidate bound $M > 0$, we have $f(x) > M$ for $0 < x < 1/M^2$, hence on an interval of positive measure. Your example is also valid.

Comment: If $\int f<\infty$ then you can derive that the set $\{f=\infty\}$ has zero measure, not that $f$ is almost everywhere bounded. Maybe you confuse almost everywhere bounded with $\mu(\{f=\infty\})=0$?

Comment: @dem0nakos Yes I think you're right. The text I am using gives a definition of measurable functions without reference to the extended real-line, for real-valued functions only, so I took $f < \infty$ a.e. to mean "almost-everywhere bounded"; I figured it wouldn't make sense for $f$ to be $\infty$ anywhere, but I think you're completely right.

Comment: What does bounded a.e. mean? Finite a.e? Less than som fixed finite number a.e?

Comment: @JonathanHole I took this to mean that there exists an $M > 0$ and a set $A$ such that $\mu(A^c) = 0$ and $f(x) < M$ for each $x \in A$.

Comment: Then your coutnerexample is perfectly fine